# Reshape pandas dataframe: Create multiple columns from one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to reshape the folowing dataframe

[image]

into

[image]

Could somebody help me with that?

Comment: You may want to try pandas `pivot` function as explained [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas converting Rows to Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50477440/pandas-converting-rows-to-columns)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `df.pivot()` or `pd.pivot()`? The values in column `C` will become column headers. After that, flatten the multi-index columns, and rename them.

```
import pandas as pd

#df = df.pivot(['A', 'B'], columns='C').reset_index()    #this also works
df = pd.pivot(data=df, index=['A', 'B'], columns='C').reset_index()
df.columns = ['A', 'B', 'X', 'Y']
print(df)
```

Output

```
   A   B  X  Y
0  a  aa  1  5
1  b  bb  6  2
2  c  cc  3  7
3  d  dd  8  4
```

Sometimes, there might be repeated records with the same index, then you'd have to use `pd.pivot_table()` instead. The param `aggfunc=np.mean` will take the mean of these repeated records, and become type `float` as you can see from the output.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.pivot_table(data=df, index=['A', 'B'], columns='C', aggfunc=np.mean).reset_index()
df.columns = ['A', 'B', 'X', 'Y']
print(df)
```

Output

```
   A   B    X    Y
0  a  aa  1.0  5.0
1  b  bb  6.0  2.0
2  c  cc  3.0  7.0
3  d  dd  8.0  4.0
```

Comment: hi would you help to validate my answer please?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```py
out = df.pivot(index=['A', 'B'], columns='C', values='D').reset_index()
```

```
print(out)

C  A   B  X  Y
0  a  aa  1  5
1  b  bb  6  2
2  c  cc  3  7
3  d  dd  8  4
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That results in the following error: *** ValueError: Length of passed values is 4, index implies. Any chance you know how to solve this?

Comment: @Beertje Do you have a multi index dataframe?